# Fail to connect to AWS IoT via mqtt.js

Tags: node.js, mqtt, aws-iot

I am trying to connect to my MQTT client on AWS IoT. I am not using the aws sdk for that but mqtt.js. Reason is that I might want to switch in the future and not use AWS at all.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mqtt = require('mqtt');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/private.pem.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/certificate.pem.crt'),
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('./certs/root.ca') ]
};

const client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://aws.com:1883', options);

const topic = 'TOPIC';

client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connect');
  client.subscribe(topic);
});

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
  const json = JSON.parse(message.toString());
  console.log(json);
});
```

> Am I missing something?

When I connect to `test.mosquitto.org`, the code works. But not with AWS.

> One of the biggest question is also: What is a clientID?

Comment: clientID is an unique identifier of your device, can be any string you want, but it is required.

Comment: As always, it was a AWS IoT policy problem. So feel free to close the question.

Comment: @ohboy21, can you please share, what you changed in the policy?

Answer (score 0):

For the future generations. I also faced that problem. As it was said in the comments the problems is related to IoT policies. In my case, I had to allow Connect action to my clientId for client config. By default when you create a thing it allows connect only from clientId like sdk-nodejs-*, sdk-java and so on.