# How to use MQTT-JS or JS AWS-SDK (node JS/JS) to send and receive data to a topic of AWS IoT

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mqtt, aws-iot

I am working on a project, in which I need to connect my devices via MQTT protocol to AWS IoT, to send and receive data.

So first I got my endpoint from the AWS Portal. Please check below screenshot:
[image]

Then I tried using `AWS Lambda` for RnD purpose, and it is working as expected. Please check below screenshot, what code I did at `AWS Lambda`:

[image]

But now I want to integrate this at the device end.

I tried [MQTT JS](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) to connect devices to AWS IoT data. Please check below code:
[image]

But this code is not working, no error I got in the output, Its just waiting.

In this code, I used the accessKey and secretKey, which I got after creating a user in `AWS-IAM`, with permission `AWSIoTDataAccess`.

I tried AWS-SDK also with the same IAM credentials. Please check below code.
[image]

But unfortunately, it is also not working.

Note: My device is just a Windows system, which will send and receive data for a topic at AWS IoT.

Please help me to solve this. Don't know what I missed. Any suggestion will be helpful for me.
Thanks,

**EDIT**:

After followed the steps mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-certs-create.html, suggested in answer by @sokkasokka. Finally getting some error at least. Please check below screenshot for the edited code and error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating AWS IoT Thing with proper permissions and use the certificates to authenticate your MQTT device.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-certs-create.html

And see this issue as well:
[Fail to connect to AWS IoT via mqtt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642803/fail-to-connect-to-aws-iot-via-mqtt-js)

Comment: Thanks @sokkasokka for reply, Is it necessary to create AWS IoT Thing? for what I needed. Or its just the certificate?

Comment: @harishsharma:  easier with a Thing, but not required.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70065117/1103511

Comment: @fedonev and Sokkasokka, I edited the question, can you please review back, now I am getting an error.

Comment: I created a thing at AWS IoT Core, download the certificate, and used the same code mentioned here with the thing certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48642803/5026957, suggested by sokkasokka, and its working. Thanks a lot. What I am missing is I tried to set a lot of MQTT connect options, but that not required.